# Failing to install SUPER video converter v2019.Build.75

Tags: windows-10, video-conversion

I am trying to install SUPER v2019.Build.75 Free edition downloaded from here: https://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html#Dnload. I have been using this tool years ago, but not lately. The current installer is crashing right after selecting language:

[image]

I have checked the folder and there are indeed a little bit too few files inside. And of course, this dll is also missing. I have tried several times, the folder looks to have the same content. I would send a support question to the developer, but I could not find any way to contact *eRightSoft*.

Comment: I guess you missed this page....https://www.erightsoft.com/contact.php

Comment: @Moab... yepp, good catch :)